# Minimal Polynomial of linear map induced by quotients space divides the minimal polynomial of itself

Tags: vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials

Suppose U is a subspace of V invariant under a linear transformation T :
V → V . Prove that T induces a linear map$ \bar T : V /U → V /U $of quotients given by $\bar T(v + U) = T(v) + U$. Prove that the minimal polynomial of $\bar T$ divides the minimal polynomial of T.

For the minimal polynomial:
The minimal polynomial of T is the monic polynomial$ m(x)∈[x]$ of least degree such that $m(T)=0$ on V.Therefore, $m(T|_u)=0$

[Minimal polynomial of restriction to invariant subspace divides minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499138/minimal-polynomial-of-restriction-to-invariant-subspace-divides-minimal-polynomi)

Should it to prove the minimal polynomial of the invariant subspace divides the minimal polynomial of T first and then continue?

Comment: Your definition of "minimal polynomial is fine, but the crucial property is this: let $m$ be the minlmal polynomial of a linear transformation $\alpha$ on $V$; then $(\forall f)( m|f \iff f(\alpha)=0)$

Comment: Can you show how should I continue then?

Comment: Well you have a lin transfm $T|_U$ and a polynomial $m$ that kills it, so ....

Comment: And if you look again you'll see that $m(\bar{T})=0$ as well. So the minimal polynomials of $T_{U}$ and $\bar{T}$ both divide the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Comment: How to show m($\bar T$)=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

$$
m(\bar{T})(v+U)=m(T)v+U=0+U
$$
where of course $0+U$ is the zero element of $V/U$.

So $m(\bar{T})=0$, and then by the basic property of minimal polynomials, the minimal polynomial of $\bar{T}$ must divide $m$.