# Given a linear map $T : \mathbb{Q}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^4$, there exists a nonzero proper subspace $V$ such that $T(V ) \subset V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Given a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{Q}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^4$, there exists a nonzero proper subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{Q}^4$ such that $T(V ) \subseteq V$.

Is the statement true?

I think the answer is no. But why? I am not sure about it. Is there any theorem which contradicts the above statement?

I also know that if the above condition holds then there exists a  $\lambda$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$ for each $v \in \mathbb{Q}^4$. Somehow this may contradicts.

Please help me.

Comment: When you say $\subset$, do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$? (This confusion is why people universally need to stop using $\subset$ when the sets are allowed to be equal. The subset notation clearly reflects $<$ and $\leq$, and using it any other way is just not right.)

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that is $\subseteq$. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed negative. Take$$T(a,b,c,d)=(-d,a,b,c).$$Then the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^4+1$. If there was such a space $V$, the minimal polynomial of $T|_V$ would [divide](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499138/446262) $x^4+1$. But it would also belong to $\Bbb Q[x]$, and $x^4+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Hello Jose  sir   why you  didn't  take  $T(a,b,c,d)=(a,b,c,d)$?

Comment: @wasiu Because then there are lots of subspaces $V$ of $\Bbb Q^4$ with $T(V)\subset V$. In fact, *every* subspace of $\Bbb Q^4$ has that property.

Comment: okay thanks you@Jose Carlos   sir